# How to compare a remote host fingerprint to the fingerprint of a different host?

Tags: ssh

I have two ways of accessing my remote host ssh server:

1. using its local IP addres
2. using its public IP address

Yesterday, I reinstalled my SSH server on the remote host and I updated my known hosts file for the **local IP address**. I am now off of my local network and trying to connect to my server using its **public IP address** and I realized I forgot to update my known hosts file after reinstalling the SSH service. This is giving me the common error below.

```
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
@    WARNING: REMOTE HOST IDENTIFICATION HAS CHANGED!     @
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
IT IS POSSIBLE THAT SOMEONE IS DOING SOMETHING NASTY!
Someone could be eavesdropping on you right now (man-in-the-middle attack)!
It is also possible that a host key has just been changed.
The fingerprint for the ECDSA key sent by the remote host is
MD5:FINGERPRINT.
Please contact your system administrator.
Add correct host key in /Users/user/.ssh/known_hosts to get rid of this message.
Offending ECDSA key in /Users/user/.ssh/known_hosts:25
ECDSA host key for [PUBLIC IP]:PORT has changed and you have requested strict checking.
Host key verification failed.
```

I'm 99% sure this is because I changed the SSH server, however, if I wanted to double check and verify, how would I do this?

## My question is

How can I verify the new fingerprint of the remote host against the fingerprint saved for the **local** IP address of the server?

## What I've Done

1. I ran the following command: `ssh-keygen -lv -f ~/.ssh/known_hosts` and found the SHA256 fingerprint saved for the **local** ip address of my server.
2. I compared this to the SHA256 fingerprint being sent to me from my remote host, and they appear to be identical.

**How can I be 100% sure? Did I do this properly?**

Answer (score 1):

When you say "updated" your known_hosts file, does that also mean you removed the old entry?

You can run this quick oneliner to quickly get the current fingerprint via local ip and public ip.

`ssh-keyscan -t rsa <Local IP of host> <Remote IP of host> | ssh-keygen -l -f -`

Here is a usage example scanning one of my Linux systems using the loopback interface as the second scan address.

```
$ ssh-keyscan -t rsa 127.0.0.1 10.10.40.20  | ssh-keygen -l -f -
# 127.0.0.1:22 SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.5
# 10.10.40.20:22 SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.5
2048 SHA256:538+RXBboFrYZDfYBdRpZs8EymGVe9SzznL7dA1jW9g 127.0.0.1 (RSA)
2048 SHA256:538+RXBboFrYZDfYBdRpZs8EymGVe9SzznL7dA1jW9g 10.10.40.20 (RSA)
```

Comment: Yes. The command I ran in order to update the local IP key-pair was `ssh-keygen -R <local IP of host>`

Comment: Have you tried running the command in my answer to compare the fingerprints? You can remove `-t rsa` or change to `-t ecdsa`. What is the output?

Comment: It won't let me print to stdin with the `-` character, it says it's not a public key file. So i'm currently trying to figure out how to create a temporary public key file

Comment: I generated a new ssh key and stored it in `testkey.pub`, then ran the command. It spit out `3072 SHA256:<fingerprint> root@HDMB.local (RSA)`. Not sure how to interpret that. The fingerprint doesn't match the old one or the new one

Comment: Please cut and paste command and output. BTW - there is no security issue sharing the fingerprint of a public key. Example, my command against two publicly accessible ssh servers.

`ssh-keyscan -t rsa panix1.panix.com panix2.panix.com | ssh-keygen -l -f -`
Output:

`2048 SHA256:Bw0LRQu5/oQYtEbPlEJ4gIQdKfpcCINn7jyI7olOC0Y panix1.panix.com (RSA)`

`2048 SHA256:5mGhppMn12SL3kJNZKAJ2UwrMa8E2MXiJTtDAa8fQPw panix2.panix.com (RSA)`